# I don't think I am using my js file in Ruby on Rails correctly

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to load new data onto a page after a user has chosen which data to load out of a list. Before the user has chosen, I want the first item on the list to show its data.

So, in my html.erb file:

```
<div id="detailsPA">
     <%=  render @app.snaps, :toolkit_view => false %>
   <div id="test">
     <%= render :partial =>'snaps/snap_details', :locals=> {:snap => @app.snaps[0]} %>
   </div>
</div>
```

@app.snaps is an array of items with a bunch of data. Here, an item in this array is called a snap.

The first render @app.snaps renders the array into links. The second, renders the data of an item in the list.

Here is the code for the list of links.

```
<%=link_to snap.name,{controller: 'snaps', action: 'snap_details', id: snap.id, remote: true}, {method: :get, class: 'snapButton'}%>
```

In order for the second render to work I have to tell it which item (or in this case snap) was chosen.

When a link is clicked on its data should replace the old data. My controller looks like:

```
def snap_details
  @snap = Snap.find(params["id"])
  render :json=>{:key=> @snap.id}
end
```

Then my js file looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.snapButton').on('ajax:success', function(event, data, status, xhr){
      $('#test').empty();
      $('#test').html("<%=escape_javascript render(:partial =>'snaps/snap_details', :locals=> {:snap => @snap})%>");
  });

});
```

But when I click on a link the new data doesn't replace the old data.

I am new to Ruby on Rails and Javascript. I feel like I am close to what I want but I am missing something very important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are rendering a json object like this: `{ key: '123' }` (only the id). You don't have access to your instance variable `@snap`.

Try the following:

```
def snap_details
  @snap = Snap.find(params["id"])
end
```

Create a new file `snap_details.js.erb` in snaps folder. Due to your are using `remote: true` in your link the request will be processed as JavaScript in your controller.

**snap_details.js.erb**

```
$('#test').empty();
$('#test').html("<%=escape_javascript render('snaps/snap_details', {snap: @snap})%>");
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah this helped a lot!! It works! But only when I click on the link twice. Would you know why it acts like this? Again, thank you so much!

Comment: I don't not why. I suggest you to see the server log and use the web inspector to track the request/response and analyze what's happening. Please consider marking the question as accepted!